# Returning client secret in plain text from GET registration request

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, registration

I was going through the [OpenID Connect Dynamic Client Registration specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html). [Section 4.3](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html#ReadResponse) lists the response for a client read request in which the client secret is displayed in plain text.

While obviously the secret needs to be returned in plain text when **registering** the client, having to return it in plain text on read requests **later** implies that the secret value itself needs to be stored (likely encrypted) instead of the salted hash of the client secret.

Since client id and secret are basically the same as username/password, I'm wondering why is the spec requiring to return a secret in plain text in this response, basically going against best practices in password storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passwords are a special kind of secret which are often memorized by users. Since users often re-use passwords, it is important not only to hash the passwords (to protect against reversing it), but also to salt it (to prevent rainbow tables from being used). Secrets such as the client_secret are usually generated from a random source and used only once. Someone who gains access from the database can therefore steal the secret, and impersonate the client, but it won't have value elsewhere.

The client secret needs to be available when a client is configured. If you are for example provisioning multiple instances of a service, you might want to dynamically obtain the client configuration including the secret when you are deploying the application.

To recap, there is a different risk model, the secret is assumed to be random and used only once, whereas passwords are often reused. The secret is supposed to contain enough entropy to protect against a brute force attack, passwords are often shorter or from a dictionary.

There is also a use case for making the secret available many times without needing to change already provisioned clients.